# Cassandra + Redis Project Server setup

Tags: server, redis, cassandra

Currently i'm having a Dedicated VPS Server with 4GB Ram , 50GB Hard-disk , i have a SAAS solution running on the server with more than 1500 customers. Now i'm going to upgrade the projects business plan,There will be 25000 customers and about 500 - 1000 customers using the project realtime . For now it takes 5 Seconds to fetch cassandra database records from the server to the application.Then i came through redis and it says that saving a copy to redis will help to fetch the data much faster and lowers server overhead.

Am i right about this ?
If i need to improve the overall performance , Can anybody tell me what are the things i need to upgrade ?
Can a server with configuration said above can handle cassandra and redis together ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: if you have queries that run 5 seconds, then you're making something wrong. Check queries - most probably they are containing ALLOW FILTERING, or doing the full scan every time

Comment: it's not the queries brother , the data fetching time from the server , No Allow Filtering used anywhere , it is modeled like that .. :)

Comment: Memory size could be too low imho. If you have 4Gb RAM, Cassandra will get only 1Gb... But it's really requires digging - look here for recommended settings, system checks, etc.: https://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/bestPractices.html

Comment: Thank you brother .. let me look into it..

Answer (score 2):

A machine with 4GB of RAM will probably only be single-core so it's too small for any production workload and only suitable for dev usage where you run 1 or 2 transactions per second, mostly for functional testing.

We generally recommend deploying Cassandra on machines with at least 2 cores + 8GB allocated to the heap (so need at least 16GB of RAM) for low production loads. For moderate loads, 4 cores + 32GB RAM is ideal so you can allocate 16GB to the heap.

If you're just at the proof-of-concept stage, there's a tier on [DataStax Astra](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) that's free forever and doesn't require a credit card to create an account. I recommend it to most people because you can launch a cluster in a few clicks and  you can quickly focus on developing your app. Cheers!

Comment: Will look into it brother , Thanks :)